# ios app wont build after removing an image, even after replacing that image

Tags: ios, swift2

I removed an image I wasnt using anymore from my swift application and now it wont build instead i get this error even after I restored the file from the recycling bin back to where it was saved. This is the error I am getting:

> CpResource /Users/Downloads/Proceed-to-Tasks-title.png
>   /Users/Josh1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WickizerApp-fiwqxewtoidlqybqaucalwazjwcy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WickizerApp.app/Proceed-to-Tasks-title.png
>       cd /Users/Josh1/Desktop/WickizerApp
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/Downloads/Proceed-to-Tasks-title.png
>   /Users/Josh1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WickizerApp-fiwqxewtoidlqybqaucalwazjwcy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WickizerApp.app
>
> error: /Users/Downloads/Proceed-to-Tasks-title.png: No such file or
>   directory

any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning (`cmd` + `shft` + `k`) and rebuilding?

Comment: Go to your derived data path and remove all the folder.After that clean build the project and run again.

Comment: try resetting your simulator or deleting the app and reloading it

Comment: tried all three, still no luck. When I clean it, it removes the error until i run it again and it comes straight back up.

Comment: Seems like you didn't copy the file into the project folder. Did you remove the file from the Project Navigator list? Also try checking `Build Phases` and see if you have a link to a file that shows up red.

Comment: Fixed it, I ended up just copying over all the main files to a new project and it runs without the error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to drag the image back into your xcassets directory if you are using assets. Otherwise you need to possibly drag it back into the directory tree in the left hand column. Merely restoring it back does not automatically add it back to your project.

If all that fails, do a global search for Proceed-to-Tasks-title via Option-Shift-Command-F and resolve all occurring paths individually.

Also as with all build issues quit Xcode and clean your DerivedData folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData).

Comment: I added it back in to the project both ways and it still didnt work, also ran that search and it came up with no results found.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the error by creating a new project and copying over all the main files, now it runs without the error.